# fscanf issue reading in from file

Tags: c, scanf

I'm basically using the C function, fscanf() to read in data from a file. using fopen and checking it I know the file is being opened successfully by checking the return value.

The file is formatted with Char, Int, Int. The issue I have is I can only read in one line at a time and the loop exits. Would appreciate if anyone could see where I am going wrong

```
char c;     
char nl;    
int t1, t2; 
int dataTest; 
do
{
    dataTest = fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d", &c, &t1, &t2);
    fscanf(fp, "%c", &nl);
    printf("%c %d %d \n", c, t1, t2);
    if (dataTest = -1)
    {
        break;
    }
}while(1);
```

Comment: strive for a minimal example. in this case most of the code(& description!) is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

`if(datatest==-1)`

rather than

`if(datatest = -1)`

One tests equality, while the other is an assignment expression. Any "assignment expression" in `C` will return the value to which the variable is assigned. So for example, `datatest= -1` will return `-1`.

Comment: ah stupid mistake! Thanks for pointing that out. waiting 10 mins as I can't give solution yet to your answer

Comment: @Bobski happens to the best of us :).